# How to refresh parentViewContoller from childViewContoller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I used `XLPagerTabStrip` for `TabBar` [Refer](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/tree/master/Sources).

Now I am doing some functionality in `childViewController` based upon that I need to update that value to `UILabel` in parent `ViewController`.

For Example:
I am getting the values in `childviewcontroller` now I want to update that value in `parentviewcontroller` as mention in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the delegate pattern ?

Comment: Use NotificationCenter to update the values

Comment: Don't use NotificationCenter to post a notification to the entire application just for a child to pass data to its parent. Children should communicate with their parents through their intimate 1:1 relationship. `parentViewController` is an instance property of all view controllers that is nil by default (you can guess when it isn't nil). The delegate pattern was also made for these moments.

Answer (score 3):

> If you don't want to use delegate then here is other solution **CallBack**
>
> In child view controller create callback function like below

```
var callback: ((_ count: Int) -> Void)?
```

> Use it when you need to update parent data

```
callback?(5)
```

> In Parent view controller when your setting your child view controller or creating instance of child view at that time write below code.

```
    childVC.callback = { (count) -> Void in
        print(count)
        //update your cart label count
    }
```